# NextJS and Strapi : fetch multiple API pages using one getStaticPaths() function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, strapi

NextJs and Strapi both explain how to pull data from a single collection type inside Strapi by doing this:

```
const pages = await (await fetch(getStrapiURL("/pages"))).json();
 const paths = pages.map((page) => {
    // Decompose the slug that was saved in Strapi
    const slugArray = page.slug.split("__");
    return {
      params: { slug: slugArray },
    };
  });
  return { paths, fallback: true };
```

}

Now my goal is to pull data from multiple collection types / pages:
Here is my current code that I am using to do this:

```
export async function getStaticPaths() {
  const [ pages, blogs ] = await Promise.all([
    fetchAPI("/pages"),
    fetchAPI("/blogs"),
  ]);
}
```

As you can see I have used a promise function to fetch multiple at the same time. 
How do I map both these pages together in a map function

Answer (score 0):

**Edits:**
I was complicating by using like this:

```
export async function getStaticPaths() {
  const [pages, blogs] = await Promise.all([
    fetchAPI("/pages"),
    fetchAPI("/blogs"),
  ]);
  const all = {pages, blogs}
  const paths = Object.keys(all).map(a => ({params: all[a]}))
  return {
    paths,
    fallback: true
  }
}
```

But while you can simply use like this:

```
export async function getStaticPaths() {
  const all = await Promise.all([
    fetchAPI("/pages"),
    fetchAPI("/blogs"),
  ]);
  const paths = all.map(a => ({params: a}))
  return {
    paths,
    fallback: true
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My route structure is like `/[category]/[id]` and maybe this will be helpful for someone:

```
export async function getStaticPaths() {
 // menu item is like {title: 'Phones', alias: '/phones', ...}
  const categoryPaths = MENU.filter(
    (item) => item.prerenderCategoryItems
  ).map(({ alias }) => alias);

  const singleProdPaths: Array<string> = [];
  // collect all single-page paths
  await Promise.all(
    categoryPaths.map(async (categoryAlias): Promise<void> => {
      const res = await fetch(
        `${env.ORIGIN}/prods-json${categoryAlias}/items.json`
      );
      const categoryItems = await res.json();
      const arrOfCategoryAliases = categoryItems.map(
        // "phones/iphone-15"
        (item) => `${categoryAlias}/${item.alias}`
      );
     
      singleProdPaths.push(...arrOfCategoryAliases);
    })
  );

  return {
    paths: singleProdPaths,
    fallback: false,
  };
}
```